# Angular passing special characters in resource params decode failing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have searching for decoding my URL substring param having forward slash which sent as `%2F` instead `/`

```
var Report = $resource('api/v1/report/:action/:key', {key:'@key'}, {
getById: {
                method: 'GET',
                params: {
                    action: 'abc/source'
                }
            },
});
```

I am getting exceptions while i was running some unit tests but however it is working with browser testing.

Error: Unexpected request: GET api/v1/report/abc%2Fsource/raj

How can make this always consider as `/`?

I also tried using javaScripts `decodeURIComponent` but it does not seem to work. Any Ideas

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to over-complicate. You can use multiple params, i.e. `var Report = $resource('api/v1/report/:action1/:action2/:key', {key:'@key'}, {
getById: {
                method: 'GET',
                params: {
                    action1: 'abc', action2: 'source'
                }
            },
});`

Comment: No i can't, because i have only one action many times except this case

Comment: Why do you need `/` in parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) is correctly converting `/` to `%2F`, As it part of URL. Seems you need to change the URL of [`$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), It can be overridden.

In resource declaration method declarion override the URL.

> url – {string} – action specific url override. The url templating is supported just like for the resource-level urls.

*Code*

```
var Report = $resource('api/v1/report/:action/:key', {
        key: '@key'
    }, {
        getById: {
            url: 'api/v1/report/:action1/:action2/:key',  //Override URL for getById
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                action1: 'abc',
                action2: 'source'
            }
        },
    });
```